# Problemas con Models y Schemas de MongoDB usando mongoose en NodeJs

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy intentando realizar una ingesta de datos en MongoDB Atlas a través de una REST Api que estoy desarrollando en NodeJs, utilizando mongoose para crear Schemas y Models.

Este es el modelo que estoy utilizando (**models/scopes**):

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const Title = {
    lang_id: String,
    value: String
};

const Description = {
    lang_id: String,
    value: String
};

const scopeSchema = new Schema({
    id: String,
    title: [Title],
    description: [Description]
});

module.exports = model('Scopes', scopeSchema);
```

Y esta es la petición post para poder adquirir los datos: **routes/scopes**

```
router.post('/pi-scopes', (req, res) => {
    const { id, title, description } = req.body;
    const newScope = new Scope({
        id,
        title: {
            lang_id: title.lang_id,
            value: title.value
        },
        description: {
            lang_id: description.lang_id,
            value: description.value
        }
    });
    console.log(newScope);
    res.send('registered');
});
```

Si realizo la **petición POST** enviando unos datos como estos:

```
{
        "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "title": [
            {
                "lang_id": "xx",
                "value": "xxx"
            }
        ],
        "description": [
            {
                "lang_id": "xxx",
                "value": "xxx"
            }
        ]
    }
```

El `console.log(newScope)` no me imprime lo deseado, le falta información:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debería de imprimirme el objeto *newScope* incluyendo los campos `title: { lang_id, value }` y `description: { lang_id, value }`, pero no me aparecen los campos correctamente.

Es decir, el contenido final que quiero guardar (el que imprimo por consola) sería este:

```
{
   "_id":"asignado po rmongo",
   "id":"asignado por mi",
   "title":[
      {
         "lang_id":"esto seria un string",
         "value":"esto seria otro string"
      }
   ],
   "description":[
      {
         "lang_id":"esto seria un string",
         "value":"esto seria otro string"
      }
   ]
}
```

¿Alguien ve el error que estoy cometiendo?

Muchas gracias de antemano por leer hasta aquí, un saludo.

Comment: que es lo que estas intentando guardar en concreto?

Comment: Seria este formato:
```
{
    _id: "asignado po rmongo",
    id: "asignado por mi",
    title: [
          {
          lang_id: "esto seria un string",
          value: "esto seria otro string"
          }
     ],
     description:  [
          {
          lang_id: "esto seria un string",
          value: "esto seria otro string"
          }
     ]
}
```
Lo añado a la pregunta asi lo puedes ver correctamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que te olvidas que description y title son un **array**, no un **objeto** para solucionarlo primero debes acceder al elemento que quieres del array y luego al objeto que esta dentro del elemento del array.

```
router.post('/pi-scopes', (req, res) => {
    const { id, title, description } = req.body;
    const newScope = new Scope({
        id,
        title: {
            lang_id: title[0].lang_id,
            value: title[0].value
        },
        description: {
            lang_id: description[0].lang_id,
            value: description[0].value
        }
    });
    console.log(newScope);
    res.send('registered');
});
```

Comment: igualmente se va a seguir mostrando solamente el _id, por que no esta guardando los datos como debe

Comment: me funcionó, de todas formas @Enzo cual sería la forma óptima de declararlo?